# JS Mocha test ES6 Babel

Tags: testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs

I'm beginner in JavaScript world and my first task is to cover an existing project with tests. We are using ES6/babel/webpack2 and it was agreed to choose Mocha/Chai as testing frameworks.

The first thing I did was creating .babelrc file in the root of the project:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
}
```

Afterwards I added the following script to package.json:

```
"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register ./src/test/*.js"
```

My simple test file looks like:

```
import {arraysAreEquals} from 'dashboard-app/utils/common-utils'
import {assert} from 'chai'

describe("common-utils", function () {

    it ("arraysAreEquals", function () {
       var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
       var array2 = [1, 2, 3];
       assert.equal(arraysAreEquals(array1, array2), true);
    });
});
```

Running my test (npm run test) I got the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'dashboard-app/utils/common-utils'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

This is quite expected as **dashboard-app** is just an alias, which is set in both **webpack.config.dev.js** and **webpack.config.prod.js**:

```
 resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname),
            "node_modules"
        ],
        alias: {
            'dashboard-app/config': 'src/config',
            'dashboard-app/utils': 'src/utils',
            .......
```

So, basically my question is how should I amend test-script in package.json in order to bind my webpack.config.dev.js (it's suitable for test env I believe)? The following didn't work for me (neither of 2 variants):

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=dev mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register ./src/test/*.js"

"test": "NODE_ENV=dev --env=dev mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register ./src/test/*.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run tests from your package.json you don't use webpack to bundle your javascript, so you have to tell to your tests how to understand that import.
You can use [mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require) lib to mockup the import of you alias. You'll write a test_helper.js file in witch there will be something like

```
mock('dashboard-app/utils/common-utils', 'src/utils/common-utils');
```

Then the npm script will be like this:

```
"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register test_helper.js ./src/test/*.js"
```